# Google Maps Api V3 load on multiple page refreshes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've this script to initialize google map.The initialize function initializes the map.The question is that it works but not for the first time when page opens.I've to refresh it two to three times for the map to show up.Why this is so?

The initialize function is being called on the body OnLoad event.

and also it is not loading in any other browser except chrome (after two to three page refreshes)

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var places=[];        //contains the addresses of markers

//Find User GeoLocation to Show On Map for the First TIme Map opens.
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition)                                                             
    }
    else
    {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
      latitude=position.coords.latitude;
      longitude= position.coords.longitude;
    }


//Initialize Google Map Api
function initialize()
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Initial Map Variables
    var myoptions={
            zoom:8,
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };  

        //Initialize Map
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myoptions);           

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say it's because it's unknown when the geolocation returns. It is asynchronous. If the map tries to load before the geolocation finishes, the variables `latitude` and `longitude` are not set and the map won't load.

Make sure the geolocation goes first and it should be fine.

https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/stackload.html

```
function getLocation() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var places=[];        //contains the addresses of markers

//Find User GeoLocation to Show On Map for the First TIme Map opens.
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, function(err) { alert(err + " " + err.code);});
    }
    else
    {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

    function showPosition(position)
    {
      latitude=position.coords.latitude;
      longitude= position.coords.longitude;
      initialize(latitude, longitude);
    }

//Initialize Google Map Api
function initialize(latitude, longitude)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //Initial Map Variables
    var myoptions={
            zoom:8,
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude),
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };  

        //Initialize Map
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myoptions);           

}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="getLocation()">

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: thnx it worked but in chrome but still it is not showing up in other browsers why???

Comment: I tried on Firefox 12.0 (worked), Opera (didn't work) and I don't have a recent IE. Do you get "geoloc error?" I'm trying to figure out how to extract more info out of the error. I'll update with anything I find

Comment: i waited a little bit and the map showed up.It worked in opera also.

Comment: Great! It would otherwise be hard for me to figure out the problem. My Opera complains of POSITION_UNAVAILABLE. I suggest adding a spinning "loading" gif to the page and remove it when loading the Google Map. And in the case of error, call the initialize function with preset lat, lng